# Problem associating my own builds with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have been developing a project for my internship for a while and I may have set up the structure incorrectly as additional updates are constantly requested during the project development process. There are 2 separate contexts in my project; one for Identity and the other for my own entities. My problem is: I want to create Identity tables according to CustomUser in EntityLayer (no problem here) and then I want to associate Identity (ie user) with my own entities. Although I haven't defined customusers in the context in dataaccess here, it goes and creates the CustomUser table and establishes the relations with it, but what I want is to set it up with Identity.

[image]

As here, relations with EmployeeDemands, EmployeeServices or other tables should be established directly with AspNetUsers, not CustomUser, and I could not solve this problem.

Code in UI Layer Context for Identity.

```
   using EntityLayer.Concrete;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace CompanyPanelUI.Data
{
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomUser>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }
       
      
   }  
   }
```

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EntityLayer.Concrete;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DataAccessLayer.Concrete
{
    public class Context:DbContext
    {

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;database=CompanyPanelNew_DB; integrated security=true;");
        }

        public DbSet<Demand> Demands {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Firm> Firms {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Service> Services {get; set;}
        public DbSet<FirmService> FirmServices {get; set;}
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set;}
        public DbSet<DemandAnswer> DemandAnswers { get; set;}
        public DbSet<DemandFile> DemandFiles { get; set;}
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DepartmentEmployee> DepartmentEmployees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeeService> EmployeeServices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeeDemand> EmployeeDemands { get; set; }

    }
}
```

EntityLayer CustomUser

```
using EntityLayer.Concrete;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EntityLayer.Concrete
{
    public class CustomUser:IdentityUser
    {
        [Display(Name = "Ad Soyad")]
        public string NameSurname { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Başvurulan Şirket")]
        public string ApplicationFirm { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Firma Id")]
        public int? FirmId { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "Bolum Id")]
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        

    }
}
```

As an example, the relationship I'm trying to establish in the EmployeeServices table.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EntityLayer.Concrete
{
    public class EmployeeService
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeServicesId { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public Service Services { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public CustomUser User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the `Users` table in your `ApplicationDbContext` like below :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomUser>
{
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder); 
            builder.Entity<CustomUser>().ToTable("CustomUser"); 
           // This will configure the table name of the Identity users table. 
           // If you wish you can rename the other tables too.           
        }
}
```

You may want to recreate the database.
And a side not you also may want to ignore the migrations generated for the `CustomUser` entity in the `Context` DbContext. To Achieve this you should configure the `CustomUser` entity in the `Context` DbContext:

```
builder.Entity<CustomUser>().ToTable("CustomUser", build => build.ExcludeFromMigrations());
```

Comment: I changed the name of the context in the UI layer that I used for Identity and hoped this would solve my problem. However, when I tried to establish my own relations in the DataAccess layer and first created the Identity tables, I got an error like this. "There is already an object named 'CustomUser' in the database."

Comment: Why does it insist on creating the CustomUser table even though I add it to the context?

Comment: When I look at the migrations, the modelBuilder entity and the custom user are determined and it is created with the create table from its name.

Comment: @MertÖzler because you have 2 DbContexts and they create their own entity. See the updated answer for the solution to that.

Comment: This solved my problem, I'm really grateful to you. I would love to be able to guide junior programmers like you one day, thanks again.